# Parse.com : Not able to receive notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

My code is as below

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.aaa"
    android:versionCode="2027"
    android:versionName="5.1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.aaa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

     <uses-permission android:name="com.aaa.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.aaa.application.SalesEnablementApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app_icon_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/application_id_stage" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="@string/client_key_stage" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.xxx.util.NetworkStateReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:label="NetworkStateReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

       .
       .
       .

        <receiver android:name="com.aaa.pushNotification.PushBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.aaa.Notification_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> -->
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.aaa.receiver.CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.aaa" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.aaa.receiver.MyReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.starter.UPDATE_STATUS" />
                <action android:name="com.aaa.UPDATE_STATUS" />
                <!--
                <action android:name="com.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.push.intent.OPEN" />
                -->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--
        <receiver
            android:name="com.aaa.receiver.MyReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.aaa" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        -->



    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Application Class:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Init Parse App after checking the current environment
    Parse.initialize(this);
    /*if(Environment.ENV.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.ENV_STAGE)){
        Parse.initialize(this,     getResources().getString(R.string.application_id_stage), getResources().getString(R.string.client_key_stage));
    }else{
        Parse.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.application_id_prod), getResources().getString(R.string.client_key_prod));
    }*/

    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    // used to store temp objects
    dataStore = new DataStore();

    eventCaptureHandler = new EventCaptureHandler(this);
}
```

I am using parse SDK version 1.13.0.
Testing on Android 6.0.1 (Sony Xperia Z2).

I try to send push message from the Parse Dashboard. I do not receive the notification sent. I noticed that DeviceType and pushType, in the Installation table, is set to (Undefined).

Comment: Are you aware that parse.com is shutting down?

Comment: I am, But currently we do not have plans to change to GCM. Atleast in next 3 - 4 months. So I have to use Parse for sending/receiving push notifications for now. Can you check what is wrong in above methods? It used to work before. Now it is not working.